# Cannot install modules

Tags: 7

I am very new to Drupal so please excuse me if this is an easily answered question.

Basically I wish to install CKEditor, however when I upload the module thorugh the online installer I am greeted with:

```
ckeditor_4.4.5_full.zip does not contain any .info files.
```

On trying to install from the URL another error:

```
The specified file temporary://files2sU5P could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.
http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/ckeditor-7.x-1.15.zip could not be saved to temporary://update-cache-ac727b57/ckeditor-7.x-1.15.zip.
Unable to retrieve Drupal project from http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/ckeditor-7.x-1.15.zip.
```

When I attempt to install a different module (weather module) to test to see if it is the module itself, again an ulgy:

```
weather-7.x-2.6.zip does not contain any .info files.
```

Finally, on an attempt to place the extracted .zip file on the webserver in the /sites/all/modules directory, nothing shows up, I only see the 'Core' modules listed.

Any suggestion as to what I should do? Any help greatly appreciated,
- Dylan.

Comment: Are you using Linux-based OS or Windows? Are you using Drush or the admin page (admin/modules) to install modules?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the settings of the "temporary directory" under File System (admin/config/media/file-system) admin page.

- Usually should be folder: `/tmp`
- Check if the folder has write access (specially for apache or the HTTP web server you are using).

You could find more info at [Drupal documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/22241).